# Call a page function from Provider in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an `Observable.timer` inside a provider which I import into a specific page. How can I call a function when the timer ends which is located inside the page not in the provider?

What I am doing now is trying to return a value when the timer ends from provider using   `.finally(() => this.endT())` but it doesn't work

**PAGE**

```
  import { TimerProvider } from '../../providers/timer/timer';

  endTimer() {
    console.log('timer ended');
  }

  newTimer() {
    this.countDown = this.timerProvider.newTimer();
    if(this.countDown == 'timer complete'){
      this.endTimer();
    }
  }
```

**PROVIDER**

```
  countDown: any;
  counter = 1*100;
  tick = 1000;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    //console.log('Hello TimerProvider Provider');
  }

  newTimer() {
     return Observable.timer(0, this.tick).take(this.counter)
     .map(() => --this.counter).finally(() => this.endT());
  }

  endT() {
    return 'timer complete';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before. There is a simple solution for this problem in JavaScript/Typescript: **callback functions**

JavaScript allows you to pass functions to another function like this:

**Your page**

```
myCallback() {
    console.log('finished');
}

myFunction() {
    // i'm calling my other function right here
    anotherFunction(myCallback);
}
```

**Your provider**

```
anotherFunction(callback) {
    // check if a callback is passed
    if (callback) {
        // execute your callback function whenever you want
        callback();
    }
}
```

You could even give data to your callback function. You may know this concept from `Promises`.

Comment: That isnt clear how I would pass it to the page from the provider? Are you saying the function is sent like thisFunction(callback()); ..

Comment: You start your timer with `newTimer()`, and you could pass your function `endTimer()` to the function like this: `newTimer(endTimer)`. In your newTimer function, you are able to execute it like this: `endTimer()` whenever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in the provider, that emits something whhen the timer ends. And in the component that uses it, you subscribe to it. This is a common pattern when writing Angular apps, using a reactive pattern.

```
//provider
public timerEvent = new EventEmitter();
//...
newTimer() {
  Observable.timer(0, this.tick).take(this.counter)
  .map(() => --this.counter)
  .finally(() => this.timerEvent.emit(null));
}

//component
newTimer() {
  this.timerProvider.timerEvent.subscribe( () => {
    //will be called when the timer from the providers ends
  });
  this.timerProvider.newTimer();
}
```